# Which is correct? “To be done business” or “to do business with”

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Could some help to clear my confusion as I am uncertain which sentence is grammatically correct:

> 1. He is not the right person to be done business with.
> 2. He is not right person to do business with.

Lastly, as far as I know "to be" is always followed by verb3rd form, but some one told me that in this case:

> ...to be doing business

is correct, but I highly doubt it.

Can some one give a link explaining this topic? I searched on Google but couldn't find *to be + ing*. It's mostly *to be* is followed by 3rd form.

Comment: "To be doing" is correct .

Comment: "to do business with" also is correct

Comment: you can download free grammar books, for example Advanced Grammar in Use by Martin Hewings or the Oxford Guide to English Grammar. I find them very useful.

Comment: Ok so it means similar form will be applied in this case aswell                                                          he is not fit to be playing with rather than to be played with ... thnx

Answer (score 1):

## 2 is correct if you mean that you will be doing business in the future and are doubtful as to whether you should do it with him.

You could use either "To do" or "To be doing" if you are currently doing business.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Thnx fr helping aidan... i m trying to spruce up my grammar... could u tell me wht kind kf sentences are these... when we use to be + ing  cz i m hving finding specific topic which could clear my confusion on how and when to use to be with ing....

Comment: These are called continuous Infinitive. Another example of it can be 'I would really like to be swimming right now'.There are also perfect and perfect continuous Infinitive and their passives are also possible.